# how to rename the property in an object using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

The question may seems like duplicate but there is a difference . i am trying to give new key which doesn't have any space.

```
{order_id :"123" , order_name : "bags" , pkg_no : "00123#"}
```

i want to rename the key as below

```
{Order Id : "123" , Order Name : "bags" , Package : "00123#" }
```

Comment: _"seems like duplicate but there is a difference"_ - There's no difference. You want to "rename" a property. What that new name is, is not relevant.

Comment: _"i am trying to give new key which doesn't have any space"_ - Why `Package` and not `Pkg No`?

Comment: Renaming a property -> duplicate, make the first letter of each word upper case -> duplicate

Comment: @Andreas when i tried with const rename = (({abc: a_b_c, ...rest}) => ({a_b_c, ...rest}))
console.log(rename({abc: 1, def: 2})) it didnt allow to specify properties with space insite rename function

Comment: [Working with Objects | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)

Comment: @Why package and not Pkg No because that is how it need to be formatted to display on  html

Comment: If you're just doing this to make presentation in a UI simpler then you might just consider a simple map at presentation time e.g. `const names={order_id:'Order Id', pkg_no:'Package'};` then map the key names using `names[obj.key] || key`. So, keep a stable data interface but customize for presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be any obvious way to rename automatically (mostly because of `pkg_no` --> `Package`), so the best you could do is have a mapping from one property name to the other and use that to reconfigure your object.

```js
const input = {order_id :"123" , order_name : "bags" , pkg_no : "00123#"}
const newProps = {order_id:"Order Id",order_name:"Order Name", pkg_no:"Package"};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(input).map( ([key,value]) => [newProps[key],value]))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the index notation to use keys like that.

```
obj['Order Id'] = obj.order_id;
```

and you can use delete eg. to remove old keys

```
delete obj.order_id;
```